# How can we limit the size of the log files generated by mongodb ? (i.e /var/log/mongodb/*.log)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, logging, ubuntu-14.04

Can we use the configuration file for limiting the log file size ?
(i.e /etc/mongod.conf)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#systemlog-options

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to limit the file size also with newer versions of MongoDB. What I currently do is to use the [logrotate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/) command via cronjob. Also keep in mind that the log cleanup must be addressed by you.

Answer (score 0):

To force `Mongodb` to rotate files without a restart you need to run these commands in `mongosh`

```
> use admin
> db.adminCommand( { logRotate: 1 } )
```

Depending on what you are using (ex: Mongoose, cron job...), you need to check file size periodically and run the command when size is too big

- Warrning you may be tempted to try `maxLogSizeKB`, however this parameters does not limit the file size.

> maxLogSizeKB limits individual attribute field in a log entry" and the the file size it self.

> Using a large value (for maxLogSizeKB), or disabling truncation with a value of 0, may adversely affect system performance and negatively impact database operations.

Answer (score -1):

in Doc - Logging Parameters - maxLogSizeKB

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/

Example, config file mongodb.conf

```
setParameter:
   maxLogSizeKB: 20
```

But number of files can be any?

Or you can use parametr - quiet

```
setParameter:
   quiet: 1
```

Comment: Neither maxLogSizeKB nor quiet do not limit the size of the log file.
[maxLogSizeKB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.maxLogSizeKB)

Comment: 'Specifies the maximum size, in kilobytes, for an individual attribute field in a log entry', `maxLogSizeKB` does not limits the size of the log file